# Rails form search or create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

In a Product model where it as an associated brand, I would like to have an input field where I can select an existing brand or add a new one.

In the form I have:

```
<%= f.fields_for :brand do |b| %>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= b.label :name, t('brand.one') %>
  <%= b.select :name, options_from_collection_for_select(Brand.all, :name, :name, product.brand.name), { include_blank: true}, class: '0select2-find-or-create' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and in the models:
Product:

```
belongs_to :brand
accepts_nested_attributes_for :brand, limit: 1
```

Brand:

```
has_many :products
```

But every time I change the Brand of a product it will change that brand's (by brand id) name, instead of changing the id.

Also for the part of creating a new brand I will try to use [select2](https://select2.github.io) with the `tags` option. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because of your `options_from_collection_for_select(Brand.all, :name, :name, product.brand.name)`

I believe for the second parameter you want `id` and not `:name`.

Reference:http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select